# session_status() keeps returning 1

Tags: php

I am using UniServerZ with the newest PHP 5.6 version and when I use

```
<?php
echo session_status();
?>
```

it simply returns 1.
I have noticed this when working with my login/signup script.

Comment: PHP is not an `addon` at all.

Comment: I know. For UniServerZ addon just means a different version of PHP.

Comment: there is a spell mistake in your code in "echo session_satus();" however its not related with the question i guess

Comment: each integer value refers to a different state, check my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

`int session_status ( void )`

> session_status() is used to return the current session status.

This returns an integer when you print it, since it is what PHP converts it into.

```
0 ----> PHP_SESSION_DISABLED if sessions are disabled.
1 ----> PHP_SESSION_NONE if sessions are enabled, but none exists.
2 ----> PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE if sessions are enabled, and one exists.
```

So basically if you check for the 1 value, it'll mean the session hasn't been started, and i you check for 2 it means the session has been started.

Comment: Yes, it should return one of these: PHP_SESSION_DISABLED,  PHP_SESSION_NONE, PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE but it returns 1 or nothing for me.

Comment: Well, there it says its return is an integer (?) @SuperLaKiller

Comment: It also says these three. But if it returned integer there would be something like 1 =  PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE or so.

Comment: @SuperLaKiller I suppose it won't print the word itself, I suppose it is converted to an integer

Comment: @JuanRocamonde the "word itself" (as you phrase it) is a defined constant, a name defined to equate to an integer value in this case

Comment: The integers are 0-indexed, so it's 0 for disabled, 1 for none and 2 for active (at least on my PHP 5.5.11 install it returns those integers for these constants).